# DataTable AsEnumerable matching a single value

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, asenumerable

Let's say my query returns a DataTable which is a list of email addresses, a single varchar column called "email"; these emails are authorized to do something.

```
jane@doe.com
mike@foo.com
donald@duck.com
```

And the current logged in user is `harry@houdini.com`.  He's not authorized. He's not on the list

Is it possible to iterate the DataRows using Linq and return a boolean `false`?

Or to return an object which is `null` or `Nothing` or empty?

In essence, I would like to know the Linq version of

```
 Authorized = List.Contains( "harry@houdini.com")
```

I would really like to know how to do this both in C# and VB.

Thanks

Comment: Use the `Any()` method to check whether any item matches your predicate.

Comment: The code that you showed *is* a valid LINQ solution to the problem.  It compiles and runs as is.

Comment: @SLaks: I'm getting an error that `'Any' is not a member of EnumerableRowCollection(Of DataRow).`  I think I may have imported the wrong library (DataSetExtensions) ?  No, System.Data.DataTableExtensions has the same error.

Comment: did you Imports `System.Linq` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is working example with `DataTable` as follows

In `C#`

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("emails");
        dt.Rows.Add("jane@doe.com");
        dt.Rows.Add("mike@foo.com");
        dt.Rows.Add("donald@duck.com");

        var authorized = dt.AsEnumerable().Any(s => s[0].Equals("mike@foo.com")); //returns True
        var notAuthorized = dt.AsEnumerable().Any(s => s[0].Equals("harry@houdini.com"));  //returns False
```

In `VB` (Converted online)

```
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
        dt.Columns.Add("emails")
        dt.Rows.Add("jane@doe.com")
        dt.Rows.Add("mike@foo.com")
        dt.Rows.Add("donald@duck.com")
        Dim authorized As var = dt.AsEnumerable.Any(() => {  }, 
           s(0).Equals("mike@foo.com"))
        Dim notAuthorized As var = dt.AsEnumerable.Any(() => {  }, 
           s(0).Equals("harry@houdini.com"))
```

Comment: I am trying to translate this to VB:  `Dim authorized as Boolean = dt.AsEnumerable().Any(Function(s) s(0).Equals("mike@foo.com"))`. I get this error: " 'Any' is not a member of 'EnumerableRowCollection(Of DataRow)".

Comment: did you  `Imports System.Linq` ?

Comment: Aha, I thought the DataTableExtensions had all that was needed. Importing Linq. Error gone.  After converting s(0).ToString.ToUpper the `Any` comparison returns true.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks but this was converted this online , Just to give idea to OP.

Answer (score 2):

`Any` is probably cleaner here:

```
bool exists = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                       .Any(r => "harry@houdini.com".Equals(r[0]));
```

You *could* project the column to a collection of strings and use `Contains`, but it seems like overkill here.

Or define a primary key and use the native `Contains` method on `DataRowCollection`:

```
dataTable.PrimaryKey = dataTable.Columns[0];
bool exists = dataTable.Rows.Contains("harry@houdini.com");
```

Comment: Why do you think that "where any item is equal to this item" is clearer than, using `Contains` when you want to find out if an item is contained in a sequence?  There's no need to use a collection to use `Contains`.

Comment: The source "collection" is a `DataTable`, so `Contains` would not work without a primary key or a custom equality comparer for `DataRow`.